# iOS tab bar item leading to Twitter

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a tab bar navigation view and I would like to use one of the tab bar items to go to a twitter link either in the twitter app or safari. When you go back to the app, I would like it to be in the same view as before the tab bar item was touched.

I'm not sure if this is possible as I am new to iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider just directly opening the twitter link when the user selects the tab, but not actually changing tabs. Just override the `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` delegate method and do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    NSInteger index = [tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    if(index == yourTwitterTabIndex){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"whatever the Twitter app url is"]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```